# Excel Sum & Max formulas of a Range that contains substring

Tags: excel, range, max, formula, sumifs

I have columns that contain the substring "Date". I want to find the latest date (MAX) and write it on cell K2

In addition, I have columns that contain the substring "Qty". I want to find the Sum of all those columns and write it on cell L2

assume I have like 50 columns so i can't select specific cells, and I must use range (probably MAXIFS or SUMFIS)

also assume I didn't know the columns letters. is it possible to add the to MAXIFS and SUMIFS a MATCH that searches for the range between "Date 1" and "Qty 5"

Help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: `Max` and `Sum` are a good place to start.

Comment: assume I have like 50 columns so i can't select specific cells, and I must use range (probably MAXIFS or SUMFIS)

Answer (score 0):

Using `MAXIFS` and `SUMIFS` First parementer is the range you want calculated, Second Parameter is your criteria range, Third parameter is the criteria itself.

Something like this should work for you.

`=MAXIFS($A2:D2,$A$1:D$1,"*Date*")`

`=SUMIFS($A2:D2,$A$1:D$1,"*Qty*")`

Just drag the ranges to match your columns.

Comment: I got this far myself it's a good solution. What if I didn't know the columns letters. is it possible to add the to MAXIFS and SUMIFS a MATCH that searches for the range between "Date 1" and "Qty 5". Thanks.

Comment: You would still need to choose which columns to check though...

Comment: I want to check the column that matches "Date 1" in $1:$1 and the column that matches "Qty 5" in $1:$1. this is the range i want

Answer (score 0):

The below formulas will work if you either:

Change the text in K1 so that it doesn't contain the word "Date", and change the text in L1 so that it doesn't contain the work "Qty"; or

Put these formulas in any row other than row 1 or 2

```
=MAXIFS($2:$2,$1:$1,"*Date*")

=SUMIFS($2:$2,$1:$1,"*Qty*")
```